# Formatar/mascarar CPF no MySQL ou PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli, sql-select

Tenho um campo "cpf" na minha tabela. Esse campo pode ser do tipo INT ou VARCHAR, caso seja preciso alterar para resolver meu problema. Nele existe apenas os valores numéricos, sem os pontos e sem hífen (.-).

No PHP, quando vou chamar os dados via `SELECT` do MySQL ou PDO, preciso formatar esse valor para que me mostre no formato 000.000.000-00 que é o padrão para CPF.
"Preciso fazer isso na query, para não ter que percorrer os dados de novo".

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Pois estou montando um Webservice que retorna um JSON com a lista de clientes. então queria evitar ter que fazer outro loop no PHP, por questão de performance.

Comment: De qualquer forma de fizer no MySQL (no Query) iria passar o processo do PHP para o MySQL. Então, de alguma forma _alguem_ iria fazer o serviço de formatar o CPF.

Comment: Se o uso é meramente visual, pode fazer isso no javascript pois pouparia execuções desnecessárias no servidor, mesmo que sejam execuções pequenas, imperceptíveis.. Não precisaria "percorrer os dados de novo" para o caso de formatar no js.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Usando a função [`INSERT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_insert)

Para acrescentar caracteres num resultado, você pode usar a função `INSERT`. Não confundir com a sintaxe `INSERT INTO`, estamos falando da função de *string*.

```
 SELECT INSERT( INSERT( INSERT( cpf, 10, 0, '-' ), 7, 0, '.' ), 4, 0, '.' )
```

Explicando:

- o `INSERT` mais interno adiciona o `-` na décima posição, e remove 0 caracteres (o segundo parâmetro numérico serve para substituição, em vez de somente inserção)
- os dois seguintes adicionam os pontos nos lugares corretos.

Sintaxe:

```
INSERT(str,pos,len,newstr)
        │   │   │    └───── string a ser inserida
        │   │   └────────── quantos caracteres serão deletados na posição
        │   └────────────── posição onde a string será inserida
        └────────────────── campo desejado ou string original
```

**Equivalente em PHP:**

```
substr_replace(substr_replace(substr_replace( $cpf, '-', 9, 0 ), '.', 6, 0 ), '.', 3, 0 );
```

### Usando [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) e [`SUBSTR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr)

Uma alternativa seria usar `SUBSTR` para pegar cada "pedaço" do CPF, e colar os pedaços e os divisores usando `CONCAT`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTR(cpf,1,3),'.',SUBSTR(cpf,4,3),'.',SUBSTR(cpf,7,3),'-',SUBSTR(cpf,10,2))
```

Acho que o `INSERT` é mais simpático neste caso (no mínimo bem mais curto de se escrever, além de se referenciar o campo em um lugar só).

De qualquer forma, o segundo exemplo pode ser útil para outros usos. Não é tão nobre como um *[kintsugi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kintsugi)*, mas o `CONCAT` tem seus momentos de glória.

**Equivalente em PHP:**

```
substr($cpf,0,3).'.'.substr($cpf,3,3).'.'.substr($cpf,6,3).'-'.substr($cpf,9,2);
```

Comment: Isso tudo sem sair do banco? Rapaz, vivendo e aprendendo a cada dia!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso criando uma FUNCTION no seu banco de dados e usa-la no seu SELECT, da seguinte forma:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION format_cpf(cpf VARCHAR(11))
RETURNS VARCHAR(14)
    BEGIN

        RETURN CONCAT( SUBSTRING(cpf,1,3) , '.',
            SUBSTRING(cpf,4,3), '.',
            SUBSTRING(cpf,7,3), '-',
            SUBSTRING(cpf,10,2));

END //
```

Uma tabela com alguns insert's de exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE pessoa (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nome VARCHAR(100),
    cpf VARCHAR(11)
);

INSERT INTO pessoa (nome, cpf) VALUES
('João', '12034578222'),
('Pedro', '12578963489'),
('Fernanda', '9657825410x');
```

O SELECT ficaria da seguinte maneira com a utilização da FUNCTION format_cpf:

```
SELECT nome, format_cpf(cpf) cpf FROM pessoa;
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Opção com PHP usando Expressão Regular:

```
<?php
$cpf = '00000000000';//000.000.000-00

$pattern = '/^([[:digit:]]{3})([[:digit:]]{3})([[:digit:]]{3})([[:digit:]]{2})$/';
$replacement = '$1.$2.$3-$4';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $cpf);//000.000.000-00
```

Dica: Você deveria usar o campo do CPF somente como varchar no banco de dados, pois em certas ocasiões existem CPF's que terminam com a letra "x".

Comment: Acho que não consegui explicar direito, mas reformulei a pergunta.

Comment: Olha uma possível solução usando FUNCTION que eu editei minha resposta.

Comment: Só pra tirar uma dúvida: Seria possível criar a function direto na query? Tipo `CREATE FUNCTION format_cpf( cpf ){...} ; SELECT format_cpf( cpf )  FROM ...`

Comment: Não precisa, você cria somente uma vez a FUNCTION, e pode usar-la quantas vezes você quiser, em qualquer query.

Comment: Então, mas digo assim, criar a function pelo PHP só para usa-la quando precisar, sem ter que configura-la no MySQL pelo PhpMyAdmin definitivamente.

Comment: Executa a query no PHP para cria-la e depois de ter usando ela, é só dar um DROP nele:
DROP FUNCTION format_cpf.

Comment: Hum! legal!! obrigado.

Answer (score -4):

SELECT J.cnpj

```
                ,CONCAT(
                
                    SUBSTR(J.CNPJ,1,2)
                    
                    ,'.'
                    
                    ,SUBSTR(J.CNPJ,3,3)
                    
                    ,'.'
                    
                    ,SUBSTR(J.CNPJ,6,3)
                    
                    ,'/'
                    
                    ,SUBSTR(J.CNPJ,9,4)
                    
                    ,'-'
                    
                    ,SUBSTR(J.CNPJ,13,2)
                    
                ) 
                
                AS 
                
                CNPJ_FORMATADO
                
                 FROM pessoa_juridica J
```

LIMIT 1