# Formatar telefones na tabela mysql

Tags: mysql, formatação

Tenho uma tabela MYSQL com o cadastro de pessoas que os telefones estão formatadas dessa forma.

```
519995150105
5133116284
51991178789
51999862438
```

O que eu preciso é de um comando que formate os telefones para ficarem assim:

```
(51)9995150105
(51)33116284
(51)991178789
(51)999862438
```

Comment: Aqui já tem uma resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113641/formatar-mascarar-cpf-no-mysql-ou-pdo ... mas pode fazer pela sua aplicação usando funções de substrings nativas para fazer o update, deve ser mais fácil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se a formatação atual for sempre como vc mencionou, é simples. Basta fazer um `replace`:

```
update tabela set telefone = replace(telefone,' 51',' (51)')
```

Apenas o primeiro telefone ficaria sem a formatação, mas aí vc pode arrumar de maneira manual ou podemos montar outro comando.

Answer (score 0):

Uso a seguinte query para formatar meus números.
Porém os meus estão armazenados sem o 55.
Pode adaptar a sua realidade:

```
select 
  numero, 
  concat('(',substr(numero_cleansed,1,2),') ',substr(numero_cleansed,3,5),'-',substr(numero_cleansed,8)) AS numero_formatted
from (
  select 
    numero, 
    replace(replace(replace(numero,'(',''),')',''),'-','') as numero_cleansed
  from chip where LENGTH(numero)=11
  ) foo
```